# Need to setup Protractor on windows

Tags: cygwin, protractor

I have been using cygwin and now I need to setup Protractor on windows.I need step by step installation guide because I am just a beginner when it comes to use cygwin. How can I setup it?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid cygwin since is not supported by NodeJS, try to follow this guide: http://elgalu.github.io/2014/run-protractor-against-internet-explorer-vm/

Comment: Too long, Should I go for linux vm on my windows?